# Which manga chapter does the season 1 of the anime end on?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I just finished watching the first season of *Nanatsu no Taizai* (*Seven Deadly Sins*). I would like to continue by reading the manga but I am unsure which chapter to start from.

Also, I read online that there is a lot missing in the anime compared to the manga. Is that true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I read the manga first and started watching the anime halfway through, **but the final episode coincides with chapter 100**, as far as I can remember.

As far as the manga goes, it has 3 arcs. The first arc ends with chapter 123. It ends kind of abruptly. So if you want to read the manga, starting from after the anime series ends, you have to start with the chapter **"Power of Love"**. I am sure it's above 101, it could be 102 or 103. So starting at 101 would be your best bet.

The anime almost covers what the manga does. Obviously, the manga might feel much granular and in-depth, but the anime gets most of the important point though. **Try reading from chapter 101**.

Comment: Do you suggest that I start reading the manga if the anime is missing a lot? The "power of love" is chapter 101 btw. Thanks for that.

Comment: yes, I would suggest you read from 101. Anime does not miss a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You should read it from the 102nd chapter. Also, there is no need to read all the chapters from the beginning, because the anime had missed a lot of parts from the manga.

While in general case manga has more to show than its anime, in this case, the leftover part in the anime is not that important and you can miss it without regrets.